# Finding polynomial Coefficients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

[image]

Let $f(x) = x^5 - x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + 8x + 4$

The root will make sure, $f(2) = 0$ Which shows:

$$2^5 - 2^4 + a2^3 + 4b + 16 + 4 = 0$$

$$16 + 8a + 4b + 20 = 0 \implies 8a + 4b = -36 \implies 2a + b = -9$$

It also follows that $f'(2) = 0$ but:

$$f'(x) = 5x^4 - 4x^3 + 3ax^2 + 2bx + 8$$

$$f'(2) = 80 - 32 + 12a + 4b + 8 = 0$$

$$12a + 4b = -56 \implies -3a - b = 14$$

The system is:

$$2a + b = -9$$
$$-3a - b = 14$$

$$-a = 5 \implies a = -5 \implies b = -19$$

Is this even correct?

**Theorem:** If $x=a$ is a double root of $f(x)$ then $f(a) = f'(a) = 0$.

*Proof:*

$$f(x) = (x-a)^2 g(x)$$

$$f'(x) = 2(x-a)g(x) + (x-a)^2g'(x)$$

$$f(a) = 0$$

$$f'(a) = 2(a-a)g(x) + (a-a)^2g(a) = 0$$

Comment: I think "double root 2" means that it has a repeated root, i.e. there should be a factor of $(x-2)^2$, not that $f'(2) = 0$ as well.

Comment: Your  approach is correct.

Comment: @walkar: having a factor $(x-2)^2$ is equivalent to $f'(2)=0$.

Comment: @walkar, please see the edit.

Comment: @sranthrop, I added a proof of that, can you check it in the post?

Comment: it's correct, but you don't need $f(a)=0$ for this part.

Comment: You should check your value of $b$. Your logic is correct but your arithmetic seems a little off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but you made a tiny mistake in solving the system. $a=-5$ is correct, but $b$ should be equal to $1$.

Comment: I know, I took $a=5$ accidently!